# if в теге input

Tags: php, if

Есть вот такой цикл:

```
<table id="items-table">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items)) {
        echo "\t\t<tr><form name="."tablerow".">\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td>Номер".$row["num"]."</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td><input type="."radio"." name="."group".$row["num"]." value="."0" .if($row["status"] == 0){echo "checked";}" >Свободная</th>"."</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td><input type="."radio"." name="."group".$row["num"]." value="."1" if($row["status"] == 1){echo "checked";} ">Продана</th>"."</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td><input type="."radio"." name="."group".$row["num"]." value="."2".if($row["status"] == 2){echo "checked";}">Резерв</th>"."</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td>" .$row["status"]."</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t\t<td><input type="."submit"." value="."Сохранить"."></th>"."</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t</form></tr>\n";
    }   
    ?>
</table>
```

По идее, он должен брать значение поля status, сравнивать его и, в зависимости от значения (0, 1, 2), чекать соответствующий radiobutton.

Ругается на наличие `if` в коде. Что не так и как исправить?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь присоединить к строке кусок функционального кода.If ничего не возвращает, соответственно не может находиться в этом месте

Comment: вы потеряли точку во втором случае перед if . но смысла коду это врядли добавит :)

Comment: @carapuz  почему же, там написано echo. только я думаю, оно вывед checked до input'a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я Вам советую использовать более подходящее форматирование и отделять разметку от кода, что бы потом не путаться в строках и не испытывать проблем с изменениями.

```
<table id="items-table">
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items)) {?>
    <tr>
        <form name="tablerow">
            <td>Номер <?= $row["num"] ?></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="group<?=$row["num"]?>" value="0" <?php if($row["status"] == 0) {echo "checked";}?> > Свободная
            </td>;
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="group<?=$row["num"]?>" value="1" <?php if($row["status"] == 1) {echo "checked";}?>> Продана
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="group<?=$row["num"]?>" value="2" <?php if($row["status"] == 2) {echo "checked";} ?>> Резерв
            </td>
            <td><?=$row["status"]?></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Сохранить"></td>
        </form>
    </tr>
<?}?>
</table>
```

Comment: При таком способе вывода шаблона лучше придерживаться альтернативного способа обращениям к пхп функций... через двоеточие. Потому, что всегда можно соотнести например `foreach` с концовкой `endforeach` а вот фигурные скобки заметить сложно и соотнести.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Очень помогло. Еще просьба, подскажите, пожалуйста, как осуществить редактирование записи в бд. Что бы значение статуса(0,1,2) менялось в зависимости от выбранного радио по нажатию кнопки сохранить?

Comment: @shuraken, попробуйте двигаться по шагам: [отправьте данные с формы на сервер](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php) указав action у формы `<form action="URL">` и принять их на тороне PHP с простым выводом через echo. Далее посмотрите как с помощью [SQL выражения UPDATE](http://siteblogger.ru/uroki-mysql/operator-obnovleniya-update.html) изменить значение в БД. Потом просто объедините получение и изменение значения в БД.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я просто не понимаю как мне получить значение выбранного радио и изменить соотв запись в таблице. Пытался через $http_get_vars["group"], но не получается

Comment: @shuraken, у вас сейчас каждая группа радио называется как groupX, где X значение $row["num"]. Если вы выполните var_dump($http_get_vars), то вы это должны увидеть(или в строке браузера, раз GET запрос). Лучше передавайте $row["num"] скрытым полем и берите его оттуда, а в радио уберите $row["num"] и тогда сможете получить его простым  $http_get_vars["group"].

Comment: @AlexKrass я пошаманил над кодом:  <?php
        $id = $row["num"];
        $status = $_GET[$http_get_vars["group"]];
        $query = "update $table set status = $status";
        mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die ("ERROR".mysql_error());
        echo $status;
        ?>

Answer (score 0):

Если сократить строки, получится, что у Вас написано следующее:

```
echo "foo" . if (something()) {echo "bar";} . "baz";
```

Это синтаксически неверно. Всё, что следует после `echo`, должно быть строкой или возвращать строку. `if`, как Вам справедливо подсказали выше, ничего не возвращает. И, очевидно, строкой не является - это логическая конструкция.

Как вариант - разбейте `echo` на несколько блоков, как-то так:

```
echo "foo";
if (something()) {echo "bar";}
echo "baz";
```

Comment: зачем!! `($row["status"] ? "checked" :'')`

Comment: И напишите, что там бардак с кавычками

Comment: @splash58 я постарался ответить наиболее доступно для уровня новичка. дать ТС короткий синтаксис if, не объяснив, почему это ему поможет, ИМХО, неправильно.

Comment: с другой стороны код с ифами уж больно будет некрасив, новичков к этому тоже не стоит приучать :)

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте вот это

```
if($row["status"] == 1){echo "checked";}
```

На вот это

```
(($row["status"] == 1) ?  "checked" : "")
```

Конечно, исправить надо во всех трех строчках.

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя написать всё по-человечески?

```
<form name="tablerow">
    <table id="items-table">
    <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($items)): ?>
        <tr>                
            <td>
                Номер<?php echo $row['num']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="group<?php echo $row['num']; ?>" value="0" <?php echo ($row["status"] == 0) ? 'checked': ''; ?>>Свободная
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="group<?php echo $row['num']; ?>" value="1" <?php echo ($row["status"] == 1) ? 'checked': ''; ?>>Продана
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="group<?php echo $row['num']; ?>" value="2" <?php echo ($row["status"] == 2) ? 'checked': ''; ?>>Резерв
            </td>               
            <td>
                <?php echo $row["status"]; ?>
            </td>       
            <td>
               <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
            </td>               
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

p.s. я не понял откуда у вас столько незакрытых `</th>`. Поэтому я их выкинул к чертям

А еще у вас `form` в цикле зачем то.... если нужно - оставьте... но всё остальное - тихий ужас

Comment: Действительно, я не заметил th незакрытые. Но вот формы лучше в цикле оставить, а то там при активации одной из многочисленных кнопок submit на сервер столько мусора уйдет.

Comment: @AlexKrass ну да. я просто не знаю чо там автор творит.